# Why does the object have no Attribute 'privileges'?

Tags: python, attributeerror

`

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.login_attempts = 0
    def describe_user (self):
        full_name = f"{self.first_name.title()} {self.last_name.title()}"
        return full_name
    def greet_user (self):
        print(f"welcome to West World, {self.first_name.title()}")
    def increment_login_attempts (self, attempts):
        """increments login attempts by 1"""
        self.login_attempts += attempts
        print(f'{self.login_attempts}')
    def reset_login_attempts (self):
        self.login_attempts = 0
        print(f'{self.login_attempts}')
class Admin (User):
    def __ini__ (self, first_name, last_name):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name)
        self.privileges = ['registrar authorization','content moderation','ad management']
    def describe_privileges (self):
        print('Admin has the following privileges:')
        for privilege in self.privileges:
           print(f'\t{privilege.title()}')
admin = Admin ('deloris','ferland')
print(admin.describe_user())
admin.greet_user()
admin.increment_login_attempts(1)
admin.describe_privileges()
```

`

I have a parent class `User`, and a child class `Admin`, which has an added attribute `self.privileges`. To run the additional attribute I also created a new method `describe_privileges` that basically prints the list that is assigned to `self.privileges`. But when I tried to execute this it kept saying "AttributeError: 'Admin' object has no attribute `privileges`". Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You have a typo in your Admin class 'def __ini__ (self, first_name, last_name)'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your Admin class never initialized self.privileges, due to not having an **init** method. This was due to a typo.

You had

```
class Admin (User):
    def __ini__ (self, first_name, last_name):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name)
        self.privileges = ['registrar authorization','content moderation','ad management']
```

Change this to

```
class Admin (User):
    def __init__ (self, first_name, last_name):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name)
        self.privileges = ['registrar authorization','content moderation','ad management']
```

and you will find self.privileges now gets initialized, and your sample code works.

Comment: Couldn't figure it out for the life of me when it was just a stupid mistake like that, ha! Thanks a lot!!